# How can i save Items in a listviewmodel in Xamarin so when i exit the app and open it again, it opens with the items which the user input

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Lets say i have a View model class called: `ToDoListViewModel`

Which looks like this:

```
public class ToDoListViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ToDoItem> ToDoItems
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ToDoListViewModel()
    {
        ToDoItems =  new ObservableCollection<ToDoItem>();

        ToDoItems.Add(new ToDoItem("to do 1", false));
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand => new Command(AddToDoItem);

    public string InputValue { get; set; }
    void AddToDoItem()
    {
        ToDoItems.Add(new ToDoItem(InputValue , false));
    }

    public ICommand RemoveCommand => new Command(RemoveItem);
    void RemoveItem(object o)
    {
        ToDoItem removeditem = o as ToDoItem;
        ToDoItems.Remove(removeditem);
    }
}
```

and the actual item:

```
public class ToDoItem
{
    public string ToDoText { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }

    public ToDoItem(string ToDoText, bool Complete)
    {
        this.ToDoText = ToDoText;
        this.Complete = Complete;
    }
}
```

I know there are a few ways of doing this, by properties or preferences, but i would appreciate if i knew how to do it cuz im a beginner programmer

Comment: use sqlite - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Answer (score 0):

> How can i save Items in a listviewmodel in Xamarin so when i exit the app and open it again, it opens with the items which the user input

As Jason's opinion, you can use Sqlite database to store data, and get data from Sqlite data and display into ListView.

I create one sample that you can take a look:

Firstly, install **sqlite-net-pcl** by **Manage Nuget Packgae**.

Then creating one model to create Sqlite Table:

```
public class ToDoItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ToDoText { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }     
}
```

add and display sqlite data UI:

```
 <StackLayout>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="to do item:" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding InputValue}" />
            <Button
                x:Name="btn1"
                Command="{Binding addcommand}"
                Text="add to do item" />
            <Button
                x:Name="btn2"
                Command="{Binding deletecommand}"
                Text="delete to do item" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ToDoText}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Add user input text into sqlite database, or delete ListView selecteditem to delete.

```
public class itemviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn;
    private List<ToDoItem> _items;
    public List<ToDoItem> items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("items");
        }
    }
    private ToDoItem _selecteditem;
    public ToDoItem selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("selecteditem");
        }
    }
    private string _InputValue;
    public string InputValue
    {
        get { return _InputValue; }
        set
        {
            _InputValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("InputValue");
        }

    }
    public ICommand addcommand { get; }

    public ICommand deletecommand { get; }
    public itemviewmodel()
    {
        conn = GetSQLiteConnection();
        conn.CreateTable<ToDoItem>();

      

        addcommand = new Command(()=> { 
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputValue))
            {
                ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();
                item.ToDoText = InputValue;
                conn.Insert(item);
                getdata();
            }
        });

        deletecommand = new Command(()=> { 
        if(selecteditem!=null)
            {
                conn.Delete(selecteditem);
                getdata();
            }
        });
        getdata();
    }
    private void getdata()
    {
        items = items = conn.Table<ToDoItem>().ToList();
    }
    public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
    {
        var fileName = "todoitem.db";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        return connection;
    }

}
```

The ViewModelBase is class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged , to notify data changed.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Binding ViewModel to current contentPage.

```
public Page12()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new itemviewmodel();
       
    }
```